# How to Hide Body but Keep Image displaying with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I have an HTML page that I want to hide everything in the body but still show just a single image on the page.  Then, I want to hide that image that was showing and then re-enable the body.

I want to do this with JavaScript that I inject into the page.  That is, when the page launches, I can run some JavaScript that I inject to do this.  My JavaScript can inject the image. Then, I need to be able to inject some JavaScript later that will turn off the image and re-show the body tag.

I can easily turn the body tag to hidden, but then that also hides my img tag that I appended to the body and that defeats my purpose.

My page is something like this:

```
<html>
<body style="display:inline">
   <p>...</p>
<body>
</html>
```

My code that has the hidden image problem is this.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display = "hidden";
console.log("about to create image");
n = document.createElement("img"); // create an image element
n.src =
  "https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_feature/public/thumbnails/image/p5020056.jpg"; // relative path to the image
document.body.appendChild(n); // append the image to the body
```

Comment: One way is to use 2 `div` elements, one with your image and one with your "body".

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't control what is in the body.  All I can do is inject javascript

Comment: Depending on what you mean by "hiding" the body, you can inject a `div` with a solid color background and use `z-index` to ensure that it sits on top of everything else. Then include your image in that `div`.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks @JackA. that sounds like it has potential. what might a div look like that covered everything?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
let newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "hide");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
document.getElementById("hide").style.zIndex = "9";
document.getElementById("hide").style.width = "100%";
document.getElementById("hide").style.height = "100%";
document.getElementById("hide").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/full_width_feature/public/thumbnails/image/p5020056.jpg')";
document.getElementById("hide").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
document.getElementById("hide").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
document.getElementById("hide").style.top = "0";
document.getElementById("hide").style.position = "fixed";
document.body.style.margin = "0";
document.body.style.padding = "0";
```

```html
<p>This is a text under the image and will not show up because the image is covering the whole area of the body !</p>
<p> I can even copy and paste this hundreds of times, but the image will still be on top of everything !</p>
<p>This is a text under the image and will not show up because the image is covering the whole area of the body !</p>
<p> I can even copy and paste this hundreds of times, but the image will still be on top of everything !</p>
<p>This is a text under the image and will not show up because the image is covering the whole area of the body !</p>
<p> I can even copy and paste this hundreds of times, but the image will still be on top of everything !</p>
<p>This is a text under the image and will not show up because the image is covering the whole area of the body !</p>
<p> I can even copy and paste this hundreds of times, but the image will still be on top of everything !</p>
<p>This is a text under the image and will not show up because the image is covering the whole area of the body !</p>
<p> I can even copy and paste this hundreds of times, but the image will still be on top of everything !</p>
<p>This is a text under the image and will not show up because the image is covering the whole area of the body !</p>
<p> I can even copy and paste this hundreds of times, but the image will still be on top of everything !</p>
<p>This is a text under the image and will not show up because the image is covering the whole area of the body !</p>
<p> I can even copy and paste this hundreds of times, but the image will still be on top of everything !</p>
<p>This is a text under the image and will not show up because the image is covering the whole area of the body !</p>
<p> I can even copy and paste this hundreds of times, but the image will still be on top of everything !</p>
```